# dict(mapping,**kwargs) vs dict(iterable,**kwargs)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Reading the Python documentation and there are a few ways of creating dictionaries.

```
dict()
dict(**kwargs)
dict(mapping, **kwargs)
dict(iterable, **kwargs)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html  (5.8 Mapping types)

I don't understand the difference between `mapping` and `iterable` - the documentation reads:

> If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same key-value pairs as the mapping object. Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object. Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects.

It seems to me that `mapping` and `iterable` are the same thing here...  Can you please help me to understand the difference?

Comment: "There is currently only one standard mapping type, the dictionary. ". I think the documentation is pretty clear here (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Comment: @Mr.E - Yeah, the OP linked that in the question. The snippet he quoted is from that section.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Accidentally send only the link :P. Corrected it

Comment: ah, so is that the difference - 'mapping' corresponds to a 'dictionary', and iterable corresponds to (for example) a list where each item is a tuple with 2 elements?

Comment: @SeanBarry: exactly that's the difference.

Comment: Not quite. The documentation uses the more abstract term of "mapping" for forward compatibility with any changes to the language.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand the difference between mapping and iterable

A mapping is a collection of key/value pairs that allow key access to value - it "maps" keys to values. The most obvious `mapping` builtin type is the `dict`.

An iterable is an object that can be iterated - which basically means you can use it in a `for obj in iterable:` statement. This include sequence types (strings, lists, etc) as well as quite a few other (files, dbapi cursors, generators etc), and, well, dicts too.

Comment: This answer is not useful. Dictionaries are iterables as well. So is a dictionary an iterable or a mapping?

Comment: @GT77 please re-read my answer - it explicitely mentions that dicts are _both_ mappings and iterables.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see some examples:

**dict()**

`a=dict()` ---> {}

**dict(**kwargs)**

`a=dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)` ---> {'one': 1,'two': 2, 'three': 3}

**dict(mapping, **kwargs)**

`a=dict({'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3})` ---> {'one': 1,'two': 2, 'three': 3}

`a=dict({'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}, four=4,five=5,six=6)`---> {{'one': 1,  'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four':4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6}

**dict(iterable, **kwarg)**

`a=dict([('one',1),('two',2),('three',3)])` ---> {'one': 1,'two': 2, 'three': 3}

`a=dict((['one',1],['two',2],['three',3]))` ---> {'one': 1,'two': 2, 'three': 3}

`a=dict([('one',1),('two',2),('three',3)], four=4,five=5,six=6)` 
---> {'one': 1,'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four':4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6}

`a=dict((['one',1],['two',2],['three',3]),four=4,five=5,six=6)` 
 ---> {'one': 1,'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four':4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6}

---

**Note:**

Calling **dict(iterable, **kwarg)** function is equal to --->

```
d={}
a=[('one',1),('two',2),('three',3)]
for k,v in a:
    d[k]=v

print(d)
```

---